# abort: error: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)

Tags: python

I am trying to clone form a mercurial repository which has https url to my local system. But am facing error saying **abort: error: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)**
I tried the command with --debug and --traceback it gave me this

```
sending capabilities command
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 191, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 924, in _dispatch
    cmdpats, cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 681, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 1055, in _runcommand
    return checkargs()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 1015, in checkargs
    return cmdfunc()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 921, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 993, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 1563, in clone
    shareopts=opts.get('shareopts'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 434, in clone
    srcpeer = peer(ui, peeropts, source)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 170, in peer
    return _peerorrepo(rui, path, create).peer()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 147, in _peerorrepo
    obj = _peerlookup(path).instance(ui, path, create)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/httppeer.py", line 281, in instance
    inst._fetchcaps()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/httppeer.py", line 76, in _fetchcaps
    self.caps = set(self._call('capabilities').split())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/httppeer.py", line 190, in _call
    fp = self._callstream(cmd, **args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/httppeer.py", line 137, in _callstream
    resp = self.urlopener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/url.py", line 383, in https_open
    return self.do_open(self._makeconnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/keepalive.py", line 257, in do_open
    raise urllib2.URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)>
abort: error: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

**Please help out with this**

Comment: this problem could be proxy related?

Comment: Hi Pinei, yes this maybe related to the proxy. working on that.

Comment: Could you figure this out?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: As of 2020 and openssl 1.1.1 this should not happen anymore, unless your endpoint does not speak tsl.

Answer (score -1):

Usually for me this is referring to a syntax error such as missing a closing ";". At least this has been what I have been running into. Line 509 is most likely not the problem so go through your code slowly but surely and make sure your syntax is correct.

Comment: Hi  Chris Hodges i just check the file, i guess there is no problem with that.